# missing file for nodejs express-generator

Tags: node.js, express-generator

I am following a tutorial in [here for Node.js + Express - Tutorial - Setup of Express](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqcBptGjHTo&index=8&list=PL55RiY5tL51oGJorjEgl6NVeDbx_fO5jR).

when I am following below codes :

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

then

```
express testjsexpress
```

then change directory & install dependencies:

```
npm install
```

and finally, run the application by

```
npm start
```

Then after calling the **localhost:3000** I observe that there are some command in output. can you explain to me why these errors are happending? I want to know what I missed and how to solve it. I mean why I am receiving 200 in front of GET /stylesheets/style.css or 404  in front of  GET /robots.txt  or   GET /favicon.ico

```
> sccjsexpress@0.0.0 start x:\Projects\sccjsexpress
> node ./bin/www

GET / 200 482.237 ms - 170
GET /robots.txt 404 526.164 ms - 1362
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 10.400 ms - 111
GET /favicon.ico 404 31.243 ms - 1362
GET / 304 14.910 ms - -
```

In my output I have below output:

> Missing helper: "Welcome"

Comment: status 404 means not found, it means those files are missing from your project

Comment: @SangramBadi: yeh that's why I was curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same steps as you were doing and it works perfectly fine. I guess you have issues with your node version.

check your current node version with the command:

```
sudo node -v
```

If you are below v8.X

then you need to upgrade node version. I am working with `node v10.8.0`

You can upgrade manage various node version with `nvm (node version manager)`

To install nvm you can follow the link [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/installing-node-js-tutorial-using-nvm-on-mac-os-x-and-ubuntu/). and follow steps :

Install the version of Node.js you want
Install the latest version with `nvm install node`
Use the latest version with `nvm use node`
Install the latest LTS version with `nvm install --lts`
Use the latest LTS version with `nvm use --lts`

Comment: version is fine v8.11.3

Comment: I think I missed something or did something wrong unexpectly. I reacreat the project and it is fine now.

Comment: Mark as verified this solution so that it would be easy for others to trust and helps.